# how to extract image using JBCroppableView

Tags: ios, uiimageview, xcode5

i am developing image based application in xcode 5. i am give 4 point for position the image using [JBCroppableVIew](https://github.com/jberlana/JBCroppableView).if user trag any point means that time image also want to extract.
please give solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

Use Pinch Gesture to add the zoom functionality in the code.
Add pinch gesture to the JBCroppableImageView Class.